# Ionic Framework - Samsung Note 8

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play, samsung-mobile

I have a question about the Play Store (I know that it outside of ionic but I figured I'd ask here anyways).  I have one of my testers using a Note 8 which after digging, I see that it is unsupported based on the following reason:

Doesn't support framework version 
21 and onwards

But reading the documentation about the  block, it says it's only needed if you change it? Digging a bit deeper, it looks like the value is in the build.gradle file.  Am I safe to just change this to a higher number?
https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZjoPA7ZBshVYP5KvrJyRESj23NIm5HriRgy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m assuming you’re using Cordova for the plugins/platforms, the docs [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/) will show you the level it supports. I would say yes, it should work. Again, assuming you’re saying framework version 21 is the Android API level, Cordova will support it. Now as far as any particular bugs with the build specifically on a Samsung Note 8, that’s a different question. I would test with the required levels and make sure your `Cordova Android Platform`

is up to date.

Comment: Thank you Stephen - looking at my issue, it turns out that Capacitor is the one who is the initial problem.  They have a default value set to 21 as the lowest.  I need to try swapping to Cordova to see.

Comment: So capacitor is at it’s early stages right now. I’m sure there’s a way to utilize capacitor and manually change the API level, but worst case I’d switch to Cordova because of maturity.